# Higher Pokedex Pokemon missing from Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I recently hatched a Magby, which is #240 in the Pokedex. As of February 2017 the highest other Pokemon I have seen are in the 170s though. Are there a lot of Pokemon from this part of the Pokedex not yet included in Pokemon Go?

## Update:

The missing Pokemon appear to be there now.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Could that question be out of date? Last it was answered was December 2016, and we're on to February now. I don't keep up with PoGo anymore so I'm not sure whether a close vote is appropriate at this time.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf There is no evidence of it being out of date. If this question included something among the lines of "I've seen this question before, but I've encountered a Pokémon not included in that list", then t would be.

Comment: Your edit does not make the other question outdated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Prior to the second generation update**

Nearly all the Pokémon from the second generation are not included yet in the game. The only second generation Pokémon present at the moment are the following:

- Pichu (#172)
- Cleffa (#173)
- Igglybuff (#174)
- Togepi (#175)
- Togetic (#176)
- Smoochum (#238)
- Elekid (#239)
- Magby (#240)

Magby being #240, it's the highest you can reach right now in the Pokédex. The highest you could reach before was Dragonite which is #149. So everything above #149 is missing in the game at the moment, except for the ones from the list above.

**Since second generation update**

It has now been possible to catch pretty much all the Pokémon of the second generation up to Ho-Oh, which is #250. Celebi is still missing.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're updating this answer and leaving the original question alone.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Sounded to me I had to go through my old answers to keep them up to date, as I have been asked to recently by another user. I guess I will just rollback it if that's a problem.

Comment: There's no point in keeping a duplicate up to date.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Answer has been rollbacked.

Comment: I mean that instead of updating the duplicate, it's better to update the original.